# using if statement inside a foreach loop

Tags: erlang

I seem to always have problems with using 2 "end"'s in the same block of code for example:

```
 Worker = fun (File) ->
 {ok, Device} = file:read_file([File]),
 Li = string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Device), "\n"),
 Check = string:join(Li, "\r\n"),
 FindStr = string:str(Check, "yellow"),
 if
  FindStr > 1 -> io:fwrite("found");
  true -> io:fwrite("not found")
 end,
end,
```

message is "syntax error before: 'end'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the comma between to end's.

```
Worker = fun (File) ->
 {ok, Device} = file:read_file([File]),
 Li = string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Device), "\n"),
 Check = string:join(Li, "\r\n"),
 FindStr = string:str(Check, "yellow"),
 if
  FindStr > 1 -> io:fwrite("found");
  true -> io:fwrite("not found")
 end
end,
```

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple - all 'statements' are to be preceded with a comma unless they
happen to be the last.

Your `if` expression is the last in the block (`fun`) passed to `foreach`. Which means it
does not need a trailing `,`.

So

```
  end
end,
```

is what you need. A simpler example:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4],
lists:foreach(
  fun(X) -> 
     Y = 1, 
     if 
       X > 1 -> io:format("then greater than 1!~n");
       true  -> io:format("else...~n")
     end 
   end, 
   L
 )
```